# Converting YYYYMMDDHHMMSS to a date and time class in r

Tags: r, lubridate, as.date

I have dataset containing date and time in the following format:

```
datetime<- c(20210830102055, 20210830102312, 20210830102335)
cycle <- c(25, 30, 35)
df <- data.frame(datetime, cycle)
df 
     datetime cycle
1 2.021083e+13    25
2 2.021083e+13    30
3 2.021083e+13    35
```

I'm trying to convert datetime column into

```
datetime2<- c("2021-08-30 10:20:55", "2021-08-30 10:23:12", "2021-08-30 10:23:35")
df <- data.frame(datetime2, cycle)
df

            datetime2 cycle
1 2021-08-30 10:20:55    25
2 2021-08-30 10:23:12    30
3 2021-08-30 10:23:35    35
```

Any efficient way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Base R:**

```
data.frame(datetime2=as.POSIXct(as.character(df$datetime),
                                format="%Y%m%d%H%M%S"), 
           cycle)
```

Output:

```
            datetime2 cycle
1 2021-08-30 10:20:55    25
2 2021-08-30 10:23:12    30
3 2021-08-30 10:23:35    35
```

The key here is `as.POSIXct` with `format`:

```
> as.POSIXct(as.character(df$datetime), format="%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
[1] "2021-08-30 10:20:55 CST" "2021-08-30 10:23:12 CST" "2021-08-30 10:23:35 CST"
>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ymd_hms()` in `lubridate` package:

```
datetime<- c(20210830102055, 20210830102312, 20210830102335)
cycle <- c(25, 30, 35)
df <- data.frame(datetime = ymd_hms(datetime), cycle)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
datetime<- c(20210830102055, 20210830102312, 20210830102335)
cycle <- c(25, 30, 35)
df <- data.frame(datetime, cycle)

# METHOD 1
df$datetime <- as.POSIXct(as.character(df$datetime) , format = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")

# METHOD 2

library(lubridate)
df$datetime <- ymd_hms(df$datetime)
```

Comment: Please write a few words about your answer and why it fixes the problem.